# Question about "lately"

Tags: adverbs, present-perfect, time

What does "lately" mean? And should I always use Perfect times if I say "lately" like this: "I have been playing a game a lot lately."  Why is "I was playing a game a lot lately" incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

*Lately* means 'recently', including up until the present time.

The inclusion of the current time is why 'was' doesn't work, because 'was' refers to a distinct period which ended at some point in the past. 'Have been' covers the same sense of period as the word 'lately'.

Answer (score 0):

> ### late·ly
>
> *adverb* \ˈlāt-lē\ 
>   in **the** recent period of time
>   <sub>Source: [merriam-webster.com definition of “lately”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lately) (emphasis mine)</sub>

The word “lately” refers to the recent past (prior to now), not merely the time shortly before a given time.

Think of it as similar to “yesterday” insofar as it is a fixed period behind the present. You wouldn’t say “Some time ago I played a game yesterday.”